# VBA Autofilter not filtering by my criteria

Tags: vba, excel, autofilter

I created a filter feature that was working before, but I left it for a couple days (over the weekend) and it doesn't filter correctly.

I have included the code below for examination.  I have run watches, and everything seems to be getting to the autofilter line correctly.  I am running out of ideas.

Is there something I may have changed on the sheet itself that is breaking autofilter?  Could I have added something in one of the criteria that is breaking it?

Thanks

NOTE: any variables not DIMed are either globals or junk variables.  Also, the index for sortfield may be off; I am working on following that.  It still seems that when filtering in the correct column, it just filters out everything.

```
Private Sub Filter_CommandButton_Click()
    'Filters by a text input and a column to filter
    Dim isInCol As Boolean
    Dim sortKey As String
    Dim sortOrder As XlSortOrder
    Dim currentData As Range
    Dim sortField As Integer ' This is the offset, determined by list index
    Dim lastRow As Integer ' used to set working range


    If filterColumn Is Nothing Then
        gojira = MsgBox("You need to enter a column to filter", vbOKOnly)
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ' Set target = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Testing_Filter_Form")
    lastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1 ' target.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1

    ' put borders around whole row
    ' target.Range(target.Cells(lastRow, 1), target.Cells(lastRow, 56)).Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous

    ' setting active sheet complete data
    Set currentData = ActiveSheet.Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1), ActiveSheet.Cells(lastRow, 12))

    ' make sort key a wildcard
    If include = True Then
        sortKey = "*" & filterText & "*"
    Else ' for excluding the entered text
        sortKey = "<>" & "*" & filterText & "*"
    End If

    ' find list index for sorting
    sortField = Me.ColumnFilter_ComboBox.ListIndex ' + 1

    ' populate sort order with value of Ascend/Descend options.
    If descend Then
        sortOrder = xlDescending
    Else
        sortOrder = xlAscending
    End If

    ' Search column to see if text exists
    isInCol = False
    For Each foo In filterColumn
        If caseSense Then
            If InStr(foo.Value, filterText) Then ' > 0 Then
                isInCol = True
                Exit For
            End If
        ElseIf Not caseSense Then
            If InStr(LCase(foo.Value), LCase(filterText)) Then
                isInCol = True
                Exit For
            End If
        End If
    Next foo

    If isInCol Then ' filter the table by the selected col; Use Range Sort
        With target
            currentData.AutoFilter Field:=sortField, Criteria1:=sortKey, VisibleDropDown:=False
            currentData.Sort key1:=filterColumn, Order1:=sortOrder, Header:=xlYes
        End With
    End If

    blah = bleh
End Sub
```

Comment: Step through the data and check what is the value of `isInCol`, `sortField`, `sortKey`

Comment: Also what is the address of `currentData`

Comment: @SiddharthRout It looks like my sortField was off by 1.  I think I left the first column of my chart out of later editions of code (just numbers to reorder list to original state), and didn't update the index correctly.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Glad it worked out for you